Approximating an equation with imaginary numbers in Sagemath
In Sagemath, I can define
u = SR.symbol('u', domain='real')

and get
solve(u^2 == u, u)

to output
Symbolic solutions: [
u == 0,
u == 1
]

However, when I introduce two variables, there are problems. For example, I would like to introduce $j$, a split-complex number, such that $j^2 =1$. To do this, I can just say
j = SR.symbol('j')
assume(j^2 == 1)

However, I then try to solve(u^2 + j*u + 1, u)  and get
Symbolic solutions: [
u == -1/2*j - 1/2*sqrt(j^2 - 4),
u == -1/2*j + 1/2*sqrt(j^2 - 4)
]

First of all, the assume function did not work. But other than that, the command solutions[0].coefficients() outputs
[[u == -1/2*j - 1/2*sqrt(j^2 - 4), 0]],

thus suggesting that Sagemath does not see u and j as separate variables, but sees the entire equation as a variable for some reason. Is there any way to get the solve on the quadratic output the results in the form u = a + b * j, where $a$ and $b$ are some numerical approximations? Please let me know. So far, I have only tried defining $j$ by using a field:
R.<j> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
K  = R.quotient(j^2 - 1)
j = K.gen()

However, this leads to multiplying $j$ with the symbolic variable $u$, which yields an error in Sagemath.

Do you know about https://ask.sagemath.org? You might find a quicker more knowledgeable answer there.

I was able to find a solution. I get u == f as an answer, so I can take the right-hand side, expand it into a series, and analyze it's coefficients.
var('j')
for sol in solutions:
    
    #expansion = sol.rhs().series(j)
    #print(expansion)
    expansion = sol.rhs().series(j).coefficients()
    print(expansion)

    sum_re = 0
    sum_im = 0

    for i in expansion:
        if i[1] % 2 == 0:
            sum_re = sum_re + i[0]
        else:
            sum_im = sum_im + i[0]

print(sum_re, sum_im) #Works!
```

